Error: unable to get local issuer certificate when using AWS RDS Proxy
I am trying to connect to an RDS Proxy endpoint (Proxy is connected to an RDS MySQL instance) with my node server running on Amazon Linux 2023 EC2 instance.
The node server is using the Fastify framework, and to connect to the Proxy, I am using the @fastify/mysql plugin. Link here: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-mysql.
The problem occurs if I enable TLS for the Proxy (if not, it is working fine).
So this is the code for the connection:
import fastifyMysql from "@fastify/mysql";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

fastify.register(fastifyMysql, {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    promise: true,
    ssl: {
      ca: readFileSync('./ap-southeast-1-bundle.pem')
    }
});

When I try to run the server, it returns the error:
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
The .pem file was downloaded to the same directory with the code using:
curl -o ap-southeast-1-bundle.pem https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-1/ap-southeast-1-bundle.pem
I would really appreciate if anyone can help!

According to the AWS documentation on using TLS with RDS Proxy:

When using a client with --ssl-mode VERIFY_CA or VERIFY_IDENTITY, specify the --ssl-ca option pointing to a CA in .pem format. For the .pem file to use, download all root CA PEMs from Amazon Trust Services and place them into a single .pem file.

Your MySQL client is indeed using the VERIFY_CA or VERIFY_IDENTITY SSL mode, so you need to use the root CA certs, not the ap-southeast-1 bundle (nor the global bundle).
Navigate to https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/, download the root CA certs, place them into a single PEM file, and substitute the path to that PEM file for ./ap-southeast-1-bundle.pem in your code.
